# Kinematics and Integration

Tags: kinematics

> A body is moving through a liquid: $$a = -\frac{v^2}{200}-32\ m/s^2$$ $$v_0 = 40\ m/s$$
>   Find an expression for the time taken, $T$, for the body to slow down to $V\ m/s$

This is from my math class, where no prior physics knowledge is required. However, I do not know a way to do this without using the physics.

I used the SUVAT equation $v = u + at$:

$$V = 40 + (\frac{v^2}{200}-32)\cdot T$$

Isolating $T$,

$$T = -200\Big(\frac{v-40}{v^2+80^2}\Big)$$

This is close to the answer given, but not quite:

> $$T = 200\int_{V}^{40}\frac{1}{v^2+80^2}dv$$

My question is, how can I get the above result using just mathematics?

Comment: Obviously, velocity can't linearly depend on time. Because the acceleration depends on velocity. You need to know that $a=dv/dt$, that's all. Then solve the ODE

Comment: Besides, $v$ is a variable (or a function) and $V$ is a constant. You can't just set $V=v$ as you did. Which level are you studying math at?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$v=v_0+at$ is only applicable if $a$ is a constant, which is not the case. You must use the definition of acceleration for this case:
$$\frac {dv}{dt}=a$$
$$dt=\frac{dv}a$$
$$\int_0^T dt=\int_{40}^V\frac {dv}{\dfrac{-v^2}{200}-32}$$
Time $0$ (initial time) corresponds to the initial velocity of $40$ while $T$ is the moment when the velocity reaches $V$.
$$T-0=\int_{40}^V\frac {dv}{\dfrac{-v^2-6400}{200}}$$
$$T=-200\int_{40}^V\frac {dv}{v^2+6400}$$
$$T=200\int_{V}^{40}\frac {dv}{v^2+80^2}$$

Comment: How did you go from the second step to the third step? You just took the integral of both sides? How did you know what limits to put on the integrand? Why didn't you put these limits on the left hand side?

Comment: @Arjun I have added a brief explanation and some clarification

Comment: I cannot thank you enough for your time...I really appreciate it!